# IDNF error in S.M.A.R.T logs

Tags: hard-drive, smart

Is it a good practice to ignore IDNF errors in smart logs if no other
evidence of problems (including smart self test and badblocks run) has been
found? Does anyone have a experience with this? The details follows.

During checks to see if a 2 year old drive is still fine (for my notebook), and I noticed the following errors in smart log (excerpt from `smartctl -a /dev/sdd`):

```
SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 33 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 33 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6 hours (0 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  10 51 00 00 00 00 00  Error:

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  a1 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:34.511  IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE
  25 00 00 00 00 00 e0 ff      00:05:34.500  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 01 00 00 00 e0 00      00:05:30.790  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 01 00 00 00 e0 00      00:05:29.550  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 01 00 00 00 e0 00      00:05:29.549  READ DMA EXT

Error 32 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6 hours (0 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  10 51 32 9c fd ff 0f  Error: IDNF 50 sectors at LBA = 0x0ffffd9c = 268434844

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 32 9c fd ff e0 00      00:00:51.163  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 32 9c fd ff 0f 04      00:00:51.156  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 32 9c fd ff e0 00      00:00:51.074  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 32 9c fd ff 0f 04      00:00:51.068  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 32 9c fd ff e0 00      00:00:50.985  READ DMA EXT
```

All remaining 3 errors stored in smart log are the same as the last one (`IDNF error at 0x0ffffd9c`).

As I understand it, the error means *sector ID not found*, so it does not directly mean that the drive is bad, but it's still fishy.

No smart attributes shows problems (eg. no reallocated sectors):

```
# smartctl --attributes /dev/sdd
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [i686-linux-3.13.10-200.fc20.i686] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   217   217   033    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1659
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       3856
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1659
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       29
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   056   056   000    Old_age   Always       -       441546
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   206   206   000    Old_age   Always       -       29 (Min/Max 14/46)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

Also smart selftest reports no problems:

```
# smartctl -t long /dev/sdd
... after a while ...
# smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdd
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [i686-linux-3.13.10-200.fc20.i686] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3853         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3851         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3847         -
```

And just to be sure, I run `badblocks` overwriting the whole disk with random data to check if there are some bad sectors. And no problems found either:

```
# badblocks -s -w -v -t random /dev/sdd
Checking for bad blocks in read-write mode
From block 0 to 312571223
Testing with random pattern: done
Reading and comparing: done
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? Did you try to change cable and power supply?

Comment: I moved mentioned HDD from one computer into another as a replacement (so I changed both cable and power supply by doing this :) and during the transition process I wanted to make sure the drive is still ok. And the smart error shown above was the only indication that something may be wrong. Now I'm using it for few months and I haven't seen any other error so far.